# How to listen for graceful server termination in grpc

Tags: go, grpc

I want to listen for graceful server termination in grpc in my handler. When the server is being stopped gracefully, I want to add some logic in my code to close open ports, files, flush results etc. How can I do that?

How is it different in case of unary and streaming handler?

Answer (score 1):

You can have shutdown hook by listening to the signals something like this

In your main function or where you start your server create channel for signals that you want to listen to

```
c := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
signal.Notify(c, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)
// call your cleanup method with this channel as a routine
go cleanup(c)
```

In your clean up method

```
func cleanup(c chan os.Signal) {
   // Wait for termination
   <- c

  // Do your cleanups here
}
```

Create the signal channel and call the `cleanup` function as a go routine before you start the gRPC server. Whenever the application (gRPC server) stopped or interrupted this channel will get the signal in the `cleanup` function where you can do the necessary cleanups

Comment: I want it to handle the gracefulstop. Also I want the rpc handler to be able to do the cleanups

Comment: This will handle the graceful stop. If you want the rpc handler to do the cleanup then you need create the signal channel in rpc handler itself

Comment: Don't forget to wait for the goroutine to finish (or timeout) before exiting the `main` function.

Answer (score 1):

For grpc servers u can do this

```
func waitForGracefulShutdown(srv *grpc.Server) {
    fmt.Println("Grpc messaging server started ...")
    interruptChan := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(interruptChan, os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)

    // Block until we receive our signal.
    <-interruptChan

    // Create a deadline to wait for.
    _, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Second*10)
    defer cancel()
    srv.GracefulStop()
    publisher, messagingError := messaging.GetPublisherInstance()
    if messagingError.Error == nil {
        publisher.Close()
    }

    log.Println("Shutting down grpc messaging server.")
    os.Exit(0)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently there's no mechanism to signal a service handler about Graceful stop. Cleanups and other such global functions that must happen upon server exiting wouldn't usually happen inside of a service handler.
That said, if you think your design is better off with such cleanups happening inside of the service handler and a signal from graceful close is critical, we would love to hear more about your use case. Perhaps open an issue on our github [repo](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go) and we can discuss it there.

Best,

Mak